# C++ COM Object Hotpatching?

Tags: c++, com, closures, hook

**Background:**

I'm hooking on windows COM object.

The method used is vtable modification. say we have an instance of **interface A** named **instance**, it contains **oldmethod** in the interface, I replaced with **newmethod**. However, in my **newmethod** I need to know the address of **oldmethod** so that I can call **oldmethod** after doing my own thing.

It is not safe to store the address of **oldmethod** in a global variable, since there might be more than one implementation behind **interface A**, let's say there are two implementations, **class A1** and **class A2**. Thus my **newmethod** needs to store both **A1->oldmethod** and **A2->oldmethod**, and call appropriate function based on the instance type.

- One way to accomplish this is that I keep a map, which stores the (address of vtable -> oldmethod). Since the address of vtable can act as a distinguisher of class A1 and class A2. In my **newmethod**, the map is checked for the correct **oldmethod** for current instance. However, this will make the program check the map every time, which imposes a cost, and thread safety on the map will increase the cost.
- Another way is to make a closure, I allocate a chunk of executable memory, and write the binary code of my **newmethod** inside(which can be reduced to the minimum size, so size is not a problem). I modify the address of **oldmethod** in the binary code for each instance. In this case there is no searching on the map cost.

**Question 1**:

Is the second way a safe way to do this, or is the first way better? Is there any potential safety problems in either of them?

**Question 2**:

In the second way, the closure I created contains class specific data, which is the oldmethod pointer. If I need to store instance specific data in my **newmethod** is there any strategy other than keeping a (this pointer -> data) map? I tried my best and couldn't find a way.

Comment: Is there some specific reason you don't just derive a coclass from the existing implementation and virtually override the 'oldmethod' with 'newmethod' The signatures *must* match or you are, by definition, violating the contract of COM for published IIDs and the interface the pin to. Unless, of course, this isn't your code (the old method) and you're basicly trying to hook someone elses coclass. You could also coclass-alias, but it sounds like you're more interested in doing this on the sly.

Comment: I'm hooking on the existing COM object to modify its behavior, I don't have the implementation.

Comment: @WhozCraig And I don't call the method directly, I also don't have the code of the caller.

Comment: *"However, this will make the program check the map every time, which imposes a cost, and thread safety on the map will increase the cost."* - that's a very invalid assumption.

Comment: I don't understand why this is invalid, do you mean that the cost is  just neglectable?

Comment: Most likely negligible. But I think if you think more in terms of "wrapping" instead of global tables and global objects, you won't need a lock at all.

Comment: Please check: Is it truly a COM object or not? Because if it is, then both the provider and the user must respect COM semantics. In particular, that means no backdoor access.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have the source to class A1, but do you control when it gets instantiated (either by "new", CoCreateInstance, or some other factory function)? If so, then just implement a class that implements interface A and just forwards all the calls on interface A to the real object and intercept the method(s) you care about.

In the example below, we show an example of replacing

```
class InterfaceA : public IUnknown
{
public:

    virtual int M1() = 0;
    virtual int M2(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual int M3() = 0;
};


class CMyWrapperClass : public InterfaceA
{
public:

    int _refcount;
    InterfaceA* _pInner;

    CSomeClass2(InterfaceA* pInner)
    {
        _pInner = pInner;
        _pInner->AddRef();
        _refcount = 1;
    }

    ~CSomeClass2()
    {
        _pInner->Release();
    }

    virtual int M1() {return _pInner->M1();}
    virtual int M2(int x, int y)  {printf("CSomeClass2::M2(x=%d, y=%d)\n", x, y); return _pInner->M2(x,y);  }
    virtual int M3() {return _pInner->M3();}

    // not shown - addRef, release, queryinterface
};


   // example instantiation
   hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_A1, NULL, CLXCTX_ALL, IID_InterfaceA, (void**)&pInterfaceA);

   // now do the wrap
   pInterfaceA = new CMyWrapperClass(pInterfaceA);
```

If you don't have control of the instantiation of the class you are trying to hotpatch, I do have code to share for that. But it's obivously a bit more complicated. If this doesn't work, I'll post another answer directly related to hotpatching a COM vtable.

Comment: I've thought about this, but I consider it not safe, in the cases that the caller knows more than just the functions in the interface. In that case, a wrapper will fail. I'm trying to find a general way that can handle all the cases and avoid danger. I'm quite interested in your other solution.

Comment: Show me an example of where the above is "not safe".

Comment: class ClassA : InterfaceA. ClassA has all the virtual functions that InterfaceA has. However, ClassA has one more method M4(), the author of the software may have knowledge of M4(), and calls M4() somewhere, but the header file provided may not contain M4 it is kept private. I know this would be a bad practice, and when writing my own program I won't do this. I said I'm trying to find a way that is perfectly safe, the program would work all the same before and after hooking.

Comment: In other words, you are worried that the internals of the software you are trying to hack, might violate the general principals of COM and unsafely downcast the interface pointer back to it's internal class without going through QueryInterface? That seems like a stretch, but I'll post another answer on patching the vtable.

Comment: @MinLin: You can't handle all cases of abuse, since there's infinitely many of them. E.g. any `inline`d call can also break things.

Answer (score 1):

It took me quite a while to understand this problem. I actually wrote out a good chunk of code that I thought to demonstrate how to patch a vtable and then invoke the original method in a wrapper class. Patching the vtable is easy.

And then I discovered the problem you are referring to. And that is when the patched vtable method is called (newmethod), even if it defined within another class, "this" is the original object and you don't have any context of which instance is being invoked. So you can't easily just reference a member variable to get back to the "oldmethod" you have saved off.

So after some thought, I think the global map is the safest approach for doing this. You likely only need a lock (critical_section) to guard inserting, removing, or looking up the function pointers in the map. You likely won't need to hold the lock while invoking the old method after you have safely retrieved it from the map. As such, the runtime overhead of doing this operation is very negligible.