# Find upper bound of vtable size at runtime

Tags: c++, runtime, vtable

Virtual table of c++ class depends on the number of virtual functions defined.
Do you have any thoughts how to get an upper bound of the v-table size at runtime?

Say I have a pointer to a object, I know its public virtual functions from the header file, but I'm not sure how many protected/private virtual functions there are.

One idea in my mind is to sequentially read down along the vtable, until:

1. I have access-violation, then this can be an upper bound of the vtable size.
2. It is NULL (But NULL can also be a  pure virtual function).

**Edit:**

Previously I have a question here: [C++ COM Object Hotpatching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919666/c-com-object-hotpatching)

I haven't get satisfactory answer. Thus I think of a way my self, which needs to hack the vtable pointer.

What I want to do is to add a variable to the c++ object during runtime. While the only thing I know about the object is that it has a vtable pointer. In order to add that field, I plan to point the vtable pointer to another place where I store a copy of its vtable. And in the upstream of this new vtable I store my added variable. That's the only solution I can think of.

The wrapping solution is not safe, coz for COM Objects, problem will arise if the object has a lot of interfaces and queryInterface is called.

And the idea to keep the new variable in a map will involve reading of the map everytime the variable is accessed.

Comment: How are you determining the vtable location? This is implementation specific, so 1 approach will not work for all.

Comment: Just a caveat, at least in MSVC, the vtables for pure virtuals are not actually null at runtime. They point to the vc runtimes default 'pure virtual method call' implementation which throws up a msgbox and then fails an assert. Code can change this at runtime by calling [_set_purecall_handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t296ys27(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @linuxuser27 For me, I'm only dealing with windows platform. let's assume the implementation by the compiler is fixed.

Comment: Why wouldn't you know the private/protected virtual functions from the header as well?

Comment: @DavidBrown I don't own the code. I only have a dll and the interface.

Comment: I don't think you can count on there being a NULL value at the end of the vtable.

Comment: @john.pavan I read from somewhere that for msvc, the vtable ends with a null just like a char array. For gcc it ends with null if there is not more vtable, but ends with 1 if there is another vtable. But I can't find a official document to confirm.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Hacking vtables is not the right approach.

Comment: @PeteBecker I'm quite sure that's what I wanna do, my previous question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14919666/c-com-object-hotpatching. And I'm not satisfied with the answer, coz I think using a wrapper is not perfectly safe.